# Capitalize name of document section when used in text sentence?

Tags: capitalization

I file briefs with appellate courts. Each brief has a section called a "Table of Contents" and one called a "Table of Authorities," where the "C" and the "A" are capitalized because those phrases are the titles of those sections.

What if I want to refer to those sections in the text of the brief or in the text of a motion accompanying the brief? Should I capitalize as it is capitalized in the titles of those sections, or treat the phrases as common nouns? E.g.,

> "I revised the table of contents in the brief."

Comment: I find it somewhat alarming that if you are already at an appellate court level, you do not already know the answer to this question... Also, it should be easy to check existing briefs, if you have Lexus-Nexus...

Answer (score 1):

You should capitalize those sections since you are referencing a specific table of contents, that is, the one in the brief. Notice how in the previous sentence, as in this one, I was merely writing about tables of content at large, and thus there is no need to change the lettering as I am not referring to a *proper noun*.

An example might read:

> The Table of Contents for this brief includes headers down to the third level and is composed of precedents organized chronologically.

Comment: Could not have been better said. Named titles should have caps.